# How to protect .txt files in android from users?

Tags: java, android, security

I have an android app which has a .txt file stored in the assets folder and the sd card. I do not want the user to be able to read or edit the contents of the file. How to make sure that no one can edit or read the file? Note: Rooted android phones allow access to the internal storage of the phone, so saving the .txt file in internal storage will not work.

Comment: A rooted device can always access the file, so the only way to prevent access is to encrypt it.

Comment: You'll need to encrypt the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encrypt the file content. The file will be always accessible but for a normal user editi it will be really difficult. Another workaround could be hide the file, in this way it is more difficult to find it

Comment: Absolutely correct sir because it can't be done to making .txt isolated from user. +1 for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you suggest a good, simple encryption method that works with Java code? Because my app's code will need to edit the file periodically.

Comment: use AES, this is the standard symmetric encryption these days.